# OpenLayers: How to show canvas as a vector

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, openlayers-3

I'm working on a project that's using maps to represent a Geo-locations.
each when I hover on any location it should bring a magnifying glass with a donut chart inside of it

I can do this by converting the donut chart from canvas to image and add it to OpenLayer vector as image.

But, the problem is this donut chart may contain a real-time data which could change each second.

So, there is anyway to directly add canvas to vector or similar way to do this.

Comment: Create an ol.Overlay containing your always updating chart.  The ol3-popup control is a good example as is the example of ol.Overlay.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Alix,
This helping me too much and solve my problem.